# Package keyval Error: letter undefined

Tags: geometry, key-value, options

I have no idea what's causing this, I have about 1800 lines of code, and no idea where the problem is. Could someone explain what the keyval package is, and what this error could possibly mean?

Comment: It might help if posted some code and at least cited the full error message. In what context does the error appear?

Comment: Many packages use `keyval` to handle their lower-level key-value interface. This means that there are a great many ways for this error to occur. I'm afraid you will have to create a short example document that reproduces the error, a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864. Even with 1800 lines of code the binary search method should allow you to find the problematic line in 12 steps.

Comment: You are using something like `\documentclass[letter]{...}` or `\usepackage[letter]{...}`

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. I found the problem

Comment: @Adam, could you tell us what the problem was?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin=1.5in, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}
```

Answer (score 3):

Found the problem, had

> \usepackage[letter, margin=1.5in, top=1.5in, bottom=1.5in]{geometry}

Removing "letter" from the package options fixed it

Comment: But then you have the predefined paper size which must not be letter by default. See my answer.